# Mongodb: how to group by key and save additional information for items in group

Tags: mongodb

I have messages system in mongodb. Messages object looks like this:

```
{
    who: String,
    whom: String,
    when: Date
}
```

So, for example, when user **1** sends message to user **2** I have:

```
{ who: "1", whom: "2", when: MSG_DATE }
```

And when user **2** sends message to **1** in response the following row is added:

```
{ who: "2", whom: "1", when: MSG_DATE }
```

Now I need to collect unique dialogs in UI for user **1**, for example.

```
[
    {
        "$match": {
            "$or": [
                { "who": "1" },
                { "whom": "1" }
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": "a",
            "dialogs_who": { "$addToSet": "$who" },
            "dialogs_whom": { "$addToSet": "$whom" }
        }
    },
    {
        "$project": {
            "name": "$_id",
            "profiles": {
                "$setUnion": [ "$dialogs_who", "$dialogs_whom" ]
            }
        }
    }
]
```

This will return me : `["1", "2"]`. In code I just skip dialog `1` for user **1**.

With this aggregation I search for messages where `who` or `whom` is user we are loading info for (**1**). Results are added to set to make it unique and finally two sets are merged into one. It works, bu I need to store latest date message for each dialog.

So if there are such rows in db:

```
{ who: "1", whom: "2", when: MSG_DATE1 },
{ who: "2", whom: "1", when: MSG_DATE2 },
{ who: "3", whom: "1", when: MSG_DATE3 },
{ who: "3", whom: "4", when: MSG_DATE4 }    // It's not dialog with 1
```

Here we have two unique dialogs (minus dialog with **1**) for user **1**: ["1", "2", "3"]. How to add into aggregation storing of latest `when` date for dialog with.

So if **MSG_DATE2** > **MSG_DATE_1** I want result like:

```
[
    "2": MSG_DATE2,
    "3": MSG_DATE4
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the most appropriate answer I can think of. It may be long, but the logic is correct.

Test date:

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("612630679bd62cd759b1df00"),
    "who" : "1",
    "whom" : "2",
    "when" : "20120820"
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("612630679bd62cd759b1df03"),
    "who" : "2",
    "whom" : "1",
    "when" : "20120822"
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("612630679bd62cd759b1df06"),
    "who" : "3",
    "whom" : "1",
    "when" : "20120825"
}

/* 4 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("612630679bd62cd759b1df09"),
    "who" : "3",
    "whom" : "4",
    "when" : "20120828"
}
```

Aggregate:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $match:{"$or":[ { "who":"1"}, {"whom":"1"} ]}
    },
    {
        $project:{ 
            who:{ 
                $first: { 
                    $filter: {
                        input: [ "$who", "$whom" ],
                        as: "i",
                        cond: { $ne: [ "$$i", "1" ] }
                    }
                }
            },
            when:1  
        }
    },
    {
        $sort:{"when":-1}
    },
    {
        $group:{_id:"$who", when:{"$first":"$when"}}
    }
])
```

Result:

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : "2",
    "when" : "20120822"
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : "3",
    "when" : "20120825"
}
```